# C++17 support in iOS/Android SDKs

Tags: android, c++, ios, c++17

Can I reuse C++17 source code of a third-party library for development of iOS/Android applications? Thanks.

Comment: Everything depends on whether the compiler, that you use, supports C++17. OS itself, doesn't know anything about syntax rules in any given language.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can in iOS.  The clang compiler used by Xcode supports this natively - just select it in the project settings.

I'd be surprised if the same wasn't true of Android.

Comment: Android r18b comes with prebuilt toolchains based on clang 7.0.2, which has had support for C++17 since version 4.

Comment: Does it also mean all the C++17 features are available as well, e.g. std::filesystem?

Comment: Should do, yes.

Comment: Nope, just checked now on a freshly installed xCode, when including filesystem header, it reports "not found".

Comment: Are you sure you selected C++17 in your build settings?

Comment: Strange.  Email Apple?

Comment: Surely older versions of iOS, e.g. 9.0, will not have libc++17 support? Or is libc++ distributed separately in the bundle?

Comment: Android finally supports `std::filesystem` with NDK v22 in Dec 2020. They still have some issues ([perm_options::nofollow](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1258), [canonical](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1260)) on older devices.